# Memory corruption in C++ linked list

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind, heap-corruption

I wrote a trivial C++ application that just reading lines from stdin and stores them in the heap in a linked list. Have no idea why does `Valgrind` abuse this code snippet... Where is that "invalid read"? Am I wrong freeing the memory allocated for the linked list in that way?

**1_9.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Node {
    std::string str;
    Node* next;
};

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* _curr = NULL;
    Node* _new = NULL;

    std::cout << "Ready for reading from stdin..." << std::endl;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        if (!head)
        {
            head = new Node;
            head->str = line;
            _curr = head;
        }
        else
        {
            _new = new Node;
            _new->str = line;
            _curr->next = _new;
            _curr = _new;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Reading finished. Here are the results:" << std::endl;
    for (Node* _node = head; _node != NULL; _node = _node->next)
    {
        std::cout << "\t" << _node->str << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Cleaning the memory..." << std::endl;
    for (Node* _node = head; _node != NULL; _node = _node->next)
    {
        std::cout << "\t Deleting:" << _node->str << std::endl;
        delete _node;
    }

    std::cout << "Bye!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**1_9.test:**

```
asdfhjkl
ASFF
12324124124
opuoiupoiu
1234
```

**Valgrind's output:**

```
[vitaly@thermaltake 01]$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --tool=memcheck ./1_9 < 1_9.test 
==4890== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4890== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4890== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4890== Command: ./1_9
==4890== 
Ready for reading from stdin...
Reading finished. Here are the results:
    asdfhjkl
    ASFF
    12324124124
    opuoiupoiu
    1234
==4890== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4890==    at 0x400E30: main (in /home/vitaly/prog/study/cpp/01/1_9)
==4890==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==4890==    at 0x4C27965: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4890==    by 0x400D63: main (in /home/vitaly/prog/study/cpp/01/1_9)
==4890== 
Cleaning the memory...
     Deleting: asdfhjkl
==4890== Invalid read of size 8
==4890==    at 0x400EA0: main (in /home/vitaly/prog/study/cpp/01/1_9)
==4890==  Address 0x5a141d8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==4890==    at 0x4C28991: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4890==    by 0x400E9B: main (in /home/vitaly/prog/study/cpp/01/1_9)
==4890== 
     Deleting: ASFF
     Deleting: 12324124124
     Deleting: opuoiupoiu
     Deleting: 1234
Bye!
==4890== 
==4890== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4890==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4890==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 30 frees, 796 bytes allocated
==4890== 
==4890== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4890== 
==4890== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4890== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

**UPD:** Added some debug output. Can't figure out why does the `invalid read` is issued during the first iteration in last loop?

Comment: Hey who voted to close this question? It is perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Andrey _"Hey who voted to close this question? ..."_ It was me (amongst others). It's arguable if asking for undefined behavior makes up a valid, researched and debugged question on SO, or it should be closed by, either hitting: 1. Could not be reproduced as from a simple/typographical error. 2. Is lacking debugging efforts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you voted for reason "must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it". It complies with this requirement. I don't think that it was the most interesting question out there but it was valid.

Comment: @Andrey I think that goes along my 2nd point. Didn't replicate the text exactly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: This is a perfectly rational question that should remain open and then be answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One guess is that you try to access deleted object:

In `for`: `_node = _node->next` after `delete node;`

Comment: Where does it do this in the case where _node is null, though? I can't see it. Surely the body of the loop isn't entered then.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with being null. Accessing _node after it is deleted is UB.

Comment: @Poldie first iteration expression is executed and then condition expression. Body is not reached. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: @Andrey, thanks. However, it is still not clear why this error does not appear in the further loop steps...? I was accessing the freed segments on the every iteration, wasn't I?

Moreover, why didn't I get SEGFAULT?

Comment: @VitalyIsaev _"... Moreover, why didn't I get SEGFAULT?"_ Undefined behavior is, ahem _undefined behavior_!